# Scipy in python - Issue with discretization

Tags: python-3.x, scipy

**Please let me know if you think this is better suited to math.stackexchange!**

I am new to python, among those who attempt to move towards open source software to be more independent. I am using Scipy package for dealing with control systems. It would take some time before I become a bit handy with debugging python. Now that the context is set, here is the problem I am facing:

I want to discretize a straight-forward transfer function and create bode plot:

```
P_d = sp.signal.cont2discrete(([1],[32,80,80,40,10,1]),0.1,method='zoh');
w_d, mag_d, phase_d = sp.signal.bode(P_d);
```

The error that I get says

```
location "location/Controller.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "location/Controller.py", line 17, in <module>
w_d, mag_d, phase_d                 = sp.signal.bode(P_d);

File "location\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\signal\ltisys.py", line 2398, in bode
w, y = freqresp(system, w=w, n=n)

File "location\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\signal\ltisys.py", line 2472, in freqresp
raise ValueError("freqresp() requires a SISO (single input, single "

ValueError: freqresp() requires a SISO (single input, single output) system.
```

I have replaced actual locations with the word itself.

From what I understand the discretization process seems to convert the *SISO* system to *not SISO*. Why? Is there a different command for making bode plots of discrete time systems in python?

Feel free to ask for clarifications if needed!

Comment: I think this is the correct place to ask this question. Why do you discretize the system before passing it to [`bode`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.19.0/reference/generated/scipy.signal.bode.html), which expects a continuous time system? You may need to use  [`dbode`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.19.0/reference/generated/scipy.signal.dbode.html) instead.

Comment: You are absolutely right...i figured as much but I just couldn't find the *dbode* command. The documentation part do not mention anything about the discrete case leading to ambiguity. But that seems to solve the purpose. Put it as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some functions in `scipy.signal` work with continuous systems and others with discrete systems. Discrete functions ofen have the same name as the continuous functions, prefixed with `d` (See [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.19.0/reference/signal.html#continuous-time-linear-systems) for an overview).
These functions represent systems as tuples and interpret them as follows.

Discrete system:

> 1. (instance of dlti)
> 2. (num, den, dt)
> 3. (zeros, poles, gain, dt)
> 4. (A, B, C, D, dt)

Continuous system:

> 1. (instance of lti)
> 2. (num, den)
> 3. (zeros, poles, gain)
> 4. (A, B, C, D)

`cont2discrete` interprets `([1], [32,80,80,40,10,1])` as case 2 (num, den). It returns a matching discrete system of the form (num, den, dt). Passing this system to `bode`, which expects a continuous system, it is interpreted as (zeros, poles, gain) with unpredictable results.

The correct function to use is [`dbode`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.19.0/reference/generated/scipy.signal.dbode.html#scipy.signal.dbode), which works correctly with the discrete (num, den, dt) system.